# Custom Alert dialog Scrolling issue

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alert box with certain edit text. I need to make it Scrollable.  I tried some methods and doesn't work it for  me.  Here is my layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:background="#da5959"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

</LinearLayout>
<!--
    </LinearLayout>
-->
```

So please help me to find some solution.

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: no errors found. but i need to make the layout scrollable for user friendly

Comment: </ScrollView> is missing at the end ?

Comment: Post your full xml containing edittext

Answer (score 2):

This way you might help to solve the problem.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
        <TextView />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this advanced dialog solution for Android : https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Could be an alternative, it handles scrolling easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works.

MainActivity.Java

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
            // Set the custom layout as alert dialog view
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            // Get the custom alert dialog view widgets reference

            // Create the alert dialog
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Set positive/yes button click listener

            // Display the custom alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();
```

alert_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:background="#da5959"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview require one parent layout and one child layout and then put your design in the child layout then scrolling working fine.
try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:background="#da5959"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test3" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```